# Exporting data from Data Grid in Dev Extreme to excel file format and saving manually to a specific folder environment

Tags: angular, typescript, devextreme, dx-data-grid

I am exporting data from dxDataGrid by using a custom button to save in excel format which is working well.  However, I would like to open File Explorer to save the excel file by opening File Explorer Dialog to choose a specific folder environment instead of automatically saving in default downloads folder.

Here's my code,

In HTML,

```
<button (click)="exportFile()">Export</button>
<dx-data-grid [dataSource]="dataList">.... </dx-data-grid>
```

In ts,

```
exportFile() {
    this.grid.export.enabled = true;
    this.grid.export.fileName = 'Report';
    this.grid.instance.exportToExcel(false); // false to export all row data
  }
```

Can you please advise how to open the File Explorer Dialog to manually save the file to a specific folder?

Thank you